# FLUTTER : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter

Im new flutter developer, Im created my first flutter project but when I click "RUN" it shows the error below. Please help

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by deleting the folder ".gradle" in "C:\Users", user = your username, even though it may look like a big folder simply delete it and run your app and the BuildTools Sdk 29.0.2 will install automatically. **This is a common error for beginners to Flutter.**

Answer (score 0):

Simply close your emulator and download the Build tools revision of the said version from Android studio.

From your Android Studio >Tools> SDK Manager> Android SDK> SDK Tools> and check the thick box Show Package Details.

In your case its 29.0.2 just follow the guide below.

After that run again the emulator using flutter.

[image]